# C++ static multi array wrapper

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, wrapper

Old c-style static arrays can be quite bothersome when passed as arguments, or returned as value. For that, the new std::array is quite convenient.

However for multi-array, there is nothing in std:: and the boost::multi_array isn't just statically allocated.

Of course, I could do, say,

`std::array<std::array<int,3>,2> my_array;`

but I find sligthly long and it corresponds to the inverted built-in declaration

`int my_array[2][3];`

I am just wondering if there is already some "library" coding such a concept (bi-dimensional or any-dimensional)

(which for the latter, if I am correct, must use some variadic template for typing e.g.

```
multi_array<int,3,4> A;
multi_array<int,3,5,8> B;
multi_array<int,4,7,8,9,8,3> C; //this one being quite rare though
```

)

EDIT : sorry about the first post, I didn't test

Comment: "but then my_array[1][2] is not the same as in (...)" What do you mean? It *is* the same.

Comment: Yes I am sorry about that, I just was absolutely sure but didn't test (I know, I know..., it's bad)

Answer (score 0):

It might be overkill for your application, but I have worked with the [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) library and think it's [family of Matrix template classes](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TutorialMatrixClass.html) might work for you.  An example:

```
Eigen::Matrix<float, 3, 2> a;
a(1,0) = 1.1;
a(0,1) = 17.5;
```

**EDIT 1:** Oops, I don't know for sure if it supports N-dimensional matrices.  But for 2-dimensional ones I know it is good.

I think you can use typedefs, either with Eigen or with `std::array`, to make your types more readable.

Comment: Thanks. I also think it's also too much for just an array without particular mathematical meaning. I am also doing linear algebra so this library could be useful however